# How do I get working folder info with JavaHg?

Tags: java, mercurial, javahg

How can I determine what changeset the current working directory of the repository is on?
`hg identity` and `hg summary` do not yet appear to be implemented in JavaHg.

A third alternative, `hg parents` is implemented, but doesn't appear to work exactly like the command line version — it looks like it shows the parents I am based off of, but not the actual changeset I am based off of. (`hg parents` on command line shows both...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Repository repo = ...
Changeset parent = repo.workingCopy().getParent1();
```

The `WorkingCopy` object also has a `getParent2()` method that is non-null if you are in a merge...

Comment: Does this already work with version 0.1, or is a 0.2-snapshot needed?

Comment: I will try this.  BTW, might want to consider deprecating `workingCopy` and rename it to `getWorkingCopy` instead (just to follow the conventions that appear to be everywhere else in JavaHg...)

Comment: The workingCopy method is not in 0.1, you 0.2-SNAPSHOT or newer. Today a release version of 0.2 was made, and current snapshot is 0.3-SNAPSHOT